# How to access entity within aggregate border

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I am currently trying to write an application in DDD allowing an entity to be created, updated and deleted. A change to an entity must be approved by  another person. The application must also keep track of what changes were made to an entity. The simplified domain model looks like this:

[image]

The application has one bounded context containing `ChangeSet`, `Enity` and `EntityHistory` where `ChangeSet` is the aggregate root. I designed the aggregate this way because of an `Entity` should not be changed without a `ChangeSet` and furthermore a `ChangeSet` should be saved together with the edited entities in one transaction. On that account I designed a single aggregate.

The design work pretty good when creating new entities:

```
private void CreateChangeSet()
{
    var repository = new ChangeSetRepository();
    var entities = new List<Entity>
    {
        new Entity(Guid.NewGuid(), "Test1", new TagStatus(1, EntityState.Pending));
    };
    var changeSet = new ChangeSet("a user", "Added a new entity", DateTime.Now, ApprovalState.Submitted, entities);
    repository.Insert(changeSet);   
}
```

However, problems arise in my design occur when I am trying to edit an entity:

```
private void EditEnity()
{
    var repository = new ChangeSetRepository();
    var entity = repository.GetEntityByName("Test1");    
    entity.AssignName("a new name");
    var entities = new List<Entity>{entity};

    var cs = new ChangeSet("a user", "Added a new entity", DateTime.Now, ApprovalState.Submitted, entities);
    repository.Insert(cs);
}
```

As far as I know an repository should return aggregates only, which would mean that in order to change an `Entity` I must first search for a `ChangeSet` which does not make sense. Is it a bad practice to return a sub-entity of an aggregate even if you perform changes only be the aggregate root?

I have searched the internet for an answer an many people are pointing out that this kind of query can point out a wrong design of aggregates. Which makes me think again if instead of one aggregate I need two aggregates one for the `ChangeSet` and one containing `Entity` and `EntityHistory`. Should I use two aggregates instead of one? If so how can I do this within a single transaction?

A further indication for two aggregates are user interface requirements like 'the user wants to see a change history for an entity' or 'show me all entities in a view'. On the one hand this indicates two aggregates on the other hand I have a feeling that `ChangeSet` and `Entities` should really belong together .

To sum up my questions:

- Should I use one or two aggregates in my design?
- If one aggregate: is it a bad practice to return a sub-entity of an aggregate even if you perform changes only through the aggregate root?
- If two aggregates: how can I save the `ChangeSet` and the associated `Entities` in one transaction?

Comment: Why don't you look at event sourcing, where events will be your history and you do not need to do anything in addition?

Comment: I will follow the suggestion of Alessandro Santini and give event sourcing a try. I had a feeling that the changeset does not fit into the model properly, event sourcing would solve this problem.

Comment: The issue here is that versioning concern is more technical and generic. Therefore, modelling it as part of the domain model can be overkill. You can also consider database versioning models, like RavenDb has a versioning bundle that keeps a certain number of versions of your documents. This is a valid approach too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- You should use one entity.
- Yes, it is bad practice as the behaviour should be exposed by the aggregate; also, reconstructing the `Entity` would require the `Entity` to know how to query `ChangeSet`; unless you orchestrate this at the service level, it is not great design.
- You should not do it, as an aggregate root represents, IMHO, a *transactional boundary*.

**Additional thoughts**

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do what *Event Sourcing* does naturally, with the addition of the approval workflow. `Events` in an Event Store are approximately what you define with a `ChangeSet`.

If this is correct, you could model this elegantly in ES by:

- Call an *Edit Entity* API that takes as input the bulk of the changes for an `Entity`
- The API:

  - Builds a `ChangeEntityCommand` from the API input (command may fail validation);
  - Retrieves the `Entity`;
  - Invokes the corresponding `Handler` in the `Entity` aggregate, which in turn emits a `ChangeQueuedForApprovalEvent`.
  - Commits the Entity in the EventStore
- An `EventHandler` will intercept the event above and take care of updating the approval view.

When the approver gives the green light, a similar flow will emit a `ChangeApprovedEvent` containing the same data of the former event. This event is the one that actually transforms the `Entity`.

Lastly, I do not believe that the ChangeSet modelling really suits DDD, as it fails to capture the intent of the change.

Hope this helps and good luck with your project.